# Tabbing does not work when adding a subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, subview

I have the following views:

[image: xib]

The xib contains a 'mainview' and a 'page1view' outlet (both NSViews).

I have the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [mainView addSubview: page1View];
}
```

Which when I run, it looks like this (as expected):

[image: Output]

The only problem is that tabbing between elements no longer works (With placeholder1.1 selected, if it hit tab, nothing happens).

Is this a bug in OSX, or am I doing something wrong here? If it is a bug, does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `nextKeyView` of the text fields to each other, if this is not tabbing in out automatically.

You can do this by selecting the text field outlet inspector view and dragging from the method name to the other text field.